# Tensorflow faster rcnn giving good detection but still detecting false positives with coco objects

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, object-detection-api

I have used the tensorflow API to detect the Guinness harp using the process described here - https://pythonprogramming.net/introduction-use-tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial/.

I have mostly good results, whenever the logo is clear in the image it finds it nicely - [image]

[image: good detection]

However, after retraining from a coco checkpoint, it still detects what I think are coco objects with a very high confidence rating i.e people, magazines. I cannot work out why this is is.

(see below)

[image: false positives]

I am using the faster_rcnn_inception_v2_coco.config found here - [https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/samples/configs/faster_rcnn_inception_v2_coco.config](http://faster_rcnn_inception_v2_coco)

Training for more steps does not seem to help as the total loss averages out. The above screenshots were from 10,000 training steps. I am training on a cpu.

I am augmenting my training images using [imgaug](https://github.com/aleju/imgaug), and an example training image can be seen below ( i have included the debug bounding box around the target) -

[image]

However, if the training images were the problem, wouldn't the graph have trouble detecting the target altogether?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue recently, from what it somewhat looks like a case of **underfitting**, I tried multiple things to improve on the results.

The thing that worked for me was actually **augmenting data** using the library **[imgaug](https://github.com/aleju/imgaug)**. You can augment the *images* as well as the *bounding boxes* using a simple script, try and increase the dataset by say 10/12 fold.

I would also suggest adding some **background images**, ie. images with no object, it was recommended by a few people in the tensorflow discussion in the issues.

Try and train the dataset again and monitor it using tensorboard. I think you will be able to reduce the number of false positives significantly.